# 'function' object has no attribute 'objects' error in django

Tags: django, database, django-models

There are many solutions present regarding this error, but still i am not getting solution to my problem.I just want to print a column value(product_title) from table (product).

> Models.py file-

```
from django.db import models
class product(models.Model):
    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    product_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images")
    product_desc = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    product_duration = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

> views.py file-

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from mutech.models import product
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse

def product(request):   
    return render_to_response('mutech/product.html',
                             {'product_row':product.objects.get(id="1") })
```

> In product.html file i am using it as-

```
<h3>{{ product_row.product_title }}</h3>
```

and getting the error-

```
'function' object has no attribute 'objects' error in django.
```

Comment: It looks like you have the same name for the function and object? Is that in the original code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the view's render_to_response dict, you're referring to `project`, your view, not `Product`, your model.

Comment: But you're still referring to `product` your view not `Product` your model. Maybe you should give the view a completely different name so you don't get confused.

Comment: thanks @Daniel Roseman, i have changed it , but i still giving same error.

Comment: No, my first comment was after your edit. **You are *still* referring to `product` the view not `Product` the model.**.

Comment: Are you talking about capital P if not then please explain the problem.

Comment: Yes, for the third time. `product` is not the same as `Product`.

Comment: hey @Daniel Roseman, i have tried updating it as all in lowercase, but it still giving the same error .

Comment: You're still importing `Product`...Keep your class names capitalized, and uppercase the query in your view. The case needs to be the same EVERYWHERE.

Comment: but when i keep class name as capital and on running command- python manage.py makemigrations . In database, table is created as all in small letters.

Comment: And why do you think that has anything to do with anything? The table name is not the same as the model name. The model is a Python class, and Python is case-sensitive.

Comment: And i am now trying to use every product in small letters.

Comment: On line eight of your views.py, you refer to product.objects. Think about where the nearest reference to "products" is to that line. It is the function definition, which is why you were getting your original error about the function not having that attribute. If you refer to your model as Product with a capital P throughout, then this should be a Product.objects, asking the class for its objects.

Comment: no i have used product as small p every where in all files, but still getting the error.

Comment: I think we are pushing you to go the other way. Every time you reference the model, make it Product (line 2 of models.py, and lines 2, 8 of views.py, where you say product.objects.). Leave product_row as is.

Comment: hello @devinformatics  thanks for answering, but i have updated every Product as product. now no confusion.

Comment: And what i am doing is correct syntactically or not ? If not please tell the correct way to fetch data from table.

Comment: But there *is* still confusion. Because now you've called your view and your model exactly the same thing. So there is no way to reference the model within that view, because Python will look up the most recent definition of the name, which will always be the view.

Comment: And the correct way, as three people have now told you, is to call your model `Product` and refer to it as that everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you are using same naming convention in both `view.py` and `model.py`. Change the function name in `views.py` either with `product_info` or something else as per your convenience.